# Decode TCP Payload data

Tags: computer-networks, communication-protocols, tcp, ip

I'm trying to find out what the data of a packet means. I'm a newbie to networking, and I try to find what's sent in this packet:
https://pastebin.com/hZEqjmBx
How can I do that? What does that data mean? How do you decode it, or is it crypted or something? I pasted the whole HEX + ASCII dump of the packet.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/124246/ip-tcp-packet-decoding-without-wireshark) question and at the relevant [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Packet_structure).

Comment: But how did he decode the payload? He just says "it decodes to", how?

Comment: The payload is encoded in ASCII, just convert each byte (two exadecimal digit) to the corresponding character using any [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Comment: It's nonsesne, it's like a Z, then nothing, nothing, N, then nothing, then 0, then nothing that's on the ASCII TABLE.